# Which Linux distribution is Google Chrome OS based on?

Tags: operating-systems, google-chrome-os

I'm interested to know which Linux distribution the upcoming Google Chrome operating system will be based on. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such details have not been released yet. Most probably it will not be based on a particular Linux OS, but they will start from scratch using the Linux kernel

Comment: Yes, and considering that they will use their own windowing system (replacing X), I don't see how can they base it on any particular distro.

Comment: Shouldn't this answer be updated?

Answer (score 6):

Google's Chrome OS is based on Debian.  See [this article](http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/News/Google-Chrome-OS-open-sourced/).

Comment: Dead link. Is there an archived copy somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Google initially used Ubuntu for Chrome OS, but began a switch to Gentoo in early 2010. Versions today currently use a Gentoo-based backend (which supplies the kernel, drivers, X.org, etc) which Google has customized to use Chrome in the traditional window-manager role. Please see [this post](https://superuser.com/a/371526/102063).

Answer (score 4):

They'll probably roll their own.  They don't have to base it on any other distribution, and they have the resources to do it.

**Edit:** Having said that, Google [apparently produce](https://serverfault.com/questions/42565/floss-server-management-and-audit-tools/42690#42690) [debmarshal](http://code.google.com/p/debmarshal/), which manages local releases on top of a .deb repository (Debian, Ubuntu, etc).  Food for thought.